# How to control formArray without formGroup?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have in such situation as I have to pass data to server like below `[1, 2, 454, 5456]`

And the data in formArray of FormGroup

I tried to create an empty array and then push empty formControl to that array but that doesn't work

```
    this._fb.group({
      content: this._fb.group({
        question: [null, Validators.required],
        media: [null, Validators.required],
        options: this._fb.array([new FormControl(null), new FormControl(null), new FormControl(null), new FormControl(null)]),
        correct_answer: [null, Validators.required],
      })
    });
```

I want options data like `['1st option', '2nd option']` But I can't able to define formControlName in template. If I define some it tries to find out the property of index of the formArray.

My expected result
`['1st option', '2nd option']`

Comment: Provide your HTML code your TS code looks good

Answer (score 0):

You just need to name the `formControls` inside your `formArray`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <! -- inside HTML do --> 
 <form [formGroup]="nameofForm" >
  <div formGroupName="content"> 
 <ng-container formArrayName="options">
    <div *ngFor="let controls of nameOfForm.get('options').controls, let i =index"> 
        <input type="text">  formControlName="i" />
   </div> 
 </ng-container>
</div>
</form>
```